# excel conditional formatting with data

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to format different columns of my excel sheet based on two conditions:
if the cell does not contain the letter "u" or the letter "r" and if it is greater than a set number.

For example, if I have a column of data, I would want 0.3 highlighted because it is greater than the set number of 0.00834 and does not contain U or R. I don't want 0.0071U to be highlighted or 0.0056J.

Any help?

Comment: Will the Alpha's always only be 1 letter in length and always at the end?

Comment: Can you please provide an example list of inputs - and what should be highlighted and what shouldn't?

Comment: if the input contains a U it should not be highlighted, but if it contains a J and is greater than the number then it should. If it contains a J and is not greater than the number it should not be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the cells/column(s) you want the conditional format applied
   to (for this example I assume you use column `B:B`)
2. Check which cell is active - the "white" cell in the blue selection. (I assume it's `B1`)
3. Create a new conditional format Home -> Conditional formatting -> New Rule
4. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
5. Enter the following formula:

   ```
   =AND(RIGHT(B1,1)<>"U",RIGHT(B1,1)<>"R",IF(ISNUMBER(B1),B1,VALUE(LEFT(B1,LEN(B1)-1)))>0.00834)
   ```

   Make sure that the `B1` is your active cell from step 2. Also make sure that it is not using any `$` to fix row or column.
   **Note:** The formula assumes that your cells contain either proper numbers - or number and a single letter at the end!
6. Set the format you wish in the Format dialog.

Done!

Comment: This will not work for number such as `0.00056J` because the last portion of you code will not work on a cell that contains a letter. It will avoid highlighting anything that does have a U or R at the end but it won't highlight cells that have a value less then the number and a letter. Because excel will not implicitly compare the numeric part of a alphanumeric string with another numeric.

Comment: @pnuts: thanks for your comments - I just edited the answer similar to your suggestion. Though it's simply not clear from the question. :-(

Comment: That is almost exactly the answer I was going to put, only difference was I was going to use `Left()*1` instead of `Value`, but both will work on the assumption the alphas will only be at the end and only 1 in length.

Comment: @user2140261: I also usually cast with `*1`, I mostly use `VALUE` on StackOverflow so new users get the core concept...

Comment: @pnuts
What if the alpha could be 1 or two letters? For example: 0.017UJ? Therefore the alpha could be 0, 1, or 2 in length. But whether or not there is a J with it, if the input has a U it should not be highlighted.